# SQLAlqhemy database operational error 11001

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**When I try to user the command db.create_all() to build my sqlalchemy database (with flask-sqlalchemy) for my flask application I get an issue, and I can not fix this, this is the error code:**

```
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 614, in connect
    (self.host, self.port), self.connect_timeout, **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 509, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 664, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbserver' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")
```

Comment: It seems a database connection error; mind sharing how you try to connect with it?

Comment: Please, provide the code, not only an error. What is the hostname of your databse server? Is it accessible to your local machine?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to answer this question, I already fixed this error, my database url was incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help other people, to fix this error I verified my database connection URL, and that was incorrect.